# How to hide a specific window in apple script

Tags: applescript

I want to have a script to show and hide a VIM window with a specific file with a keyboard shortcut (will be done over BetterTouchTool). I have everything in the script working, expect the hiding of the window.

I tried to find the opposite of `AXRaise`, but had no luck to find some documentation regarding this.

#### toogle-journal.scpt

```
if application "MacVim" is running then
    log "macvim running"
    tell application "System Events"
        log "tell app system events"
        tell application process "MacVim"
            log "- tell app process macvim"
            if exists (first window whose name contains "journal") then
                log "-- window contains journal"
                # @todo have to toggle between visible and not visible
                if (get frontmost) then
                    log "true: " & (get frontmost)
                    # How to hide the window ??
                else
                    log "false: " & (get frontmost)
                    # set visible to true
                    # set frontmost to true
                    perform action "AXRaise" of (first window whose name contains "journal")
                end if
            else
                log "- no window with journal"
                do shell script "/Users/foobar/bin/jo > /dev/null 2>&1 &"
            end if
        end tell
    end tell
else
    log "no macvim running"
    do shell script "/Users/foobar/bin/jo > /dev/null 2>&1 &"
end if
```

Comment: If by "hide the window" you mean to _minimize_ it and **MacVim** is the active frontmost _application_ then, `tell application "MacVim" to set miniaturized of (first window whose name contains "journal") to true` will hide the target _window_. If **MacVim** is **not** the active frontmost _application_, then `tell application "System Events" to tell application "MacVim" to set miniaturized of (first window whose name contains "journal") to true` will hide the target _window_.  If this is what you are looking for, let me know and I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: @user3439894 minimize would be fine as well. How do I maximze then? Is it ``miniaturized to false``? There must be as well a kind of hinding feature in applescript as iTerm and Bettertouchtool can do this, but I am not aware how.

Answer (score 2):

In the context of *basic vanilla* **AppleScript**, here are two ways the *window* of an *application* can be *hidden*.

- If the `miniaturizable` *property* is `true`, setting its `miniaturized` *property* to: `true`
- Set its `visible` *property* to: `false`

  - Note: When setting the `visible` *property* of a *window* to `false`, it no longer appears in the list of open windows shown under the **Window** menu in its **UI**, and will remain that way until it's reset to `true`, while the *application* is still running.
  - Closing **MacVim**, normally, with a *window* still hidden in this manner should cause a **Quit without saving?** There are modified buffers, if you quit now all changes will be lost. Quit anyway? [Cancel] [Quit] *dialog box*.

---

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

- If **MacVim** is the active frontmost *application* then:

**To *hide* by minimizing:**

```applescript
tell application "MacVim" to ¬
    set miniaturized of ¬
        (first window whose name contains "journal") to true
```

**To *unhide* when `miniaturized` is set to: `true`**

```applescript
tell application "MacVim" to ¬
    set miniaturized of ¬
        (first window whose name contains "journal") to false
```

**Or:**

```applescript
tell application "MacVim" to ¬
    set visible of ¬
        (first window whose name contains "journal") to true
```

---

**To *hide* by setting `visible` to: `false`**

```applescript
tell application "MacVim" to ¬
    set visible of ¬
        (first window whose name contains "journal") to false
```

**To *unhide* by setting `visible` to: `true`**

```applescript
tell application "MacVim" to ¬
    set visible of ¬
        (first window whose name contains "journal") to true
```

---

- If **MacVim** is **not** the active frontmost *application*, then perform any of the above under **System Events**, e.g.:

```applescript
tell application "System Events" to ¬
    tell application "MacVim" to ¬
        set miniaturized of ¬
            (first window whose name contains "journal") to true
```

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: ``set miniaturized to true/false`` works more or less. Problem: If I ``set miniaturized to true`` the windows minimzes to the dock. But MacVim App is still active (you see it on the topbar). Then the ``set miniaturized to false`` will not work. It works first, if MacVim is not the active  application, e.g. if I switch to Finder. How to tackle this?

Comment: @jerik, RE: from your comment, "if MacVim is not the active application, e.g. if I switch to Finder. How to tackle this? " --    The - If **MacVim** is **not** the active frontmost _application_, then perform any of the above under **System Events**, e.g.: _section_ of my answer covers that scenario.